# Button text Issue

Tags: css

I have a button on my form with the fixed width. Text of that button is dynamic: 
[image: Dynamic text 1]

If length of that dynamic text  greater than 100px, I am faced with this:
[image: Dynamic Text 2]

This is how my code looks like

```
<button id="btn" type="buttson" style="width:120px;color:red" class="btn btn-primary">
    <span>Dynamic Textttttttttttttttttttttttt</span>
</button>
```

How can I make the text to not overflow the button?

Comment: can you please add a snippet with relevant code (HTML and CSS)?

Comment: remove button width from your css

Comment: Can you post your HTML and CSS relevant to the button?

Comment: If you ask a question here, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so others can see the problem on their system. Without, we are not able to help.

Answer (score 3):

**1)**   If you want your button width to be fixed and then handle the long texts, then use text overflow **[Elipses](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/)**, add this rule in your css. This will make your text something like `Dynamic Textt..` up to the width of the button.

```
button span{
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

---

**2)** If you want to Increase the button width along with the text. Then use the solution provided by **[LGSon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35986438/button-text-issue/35986502#35986502)** ie; change the `wdith:120px` to `min-width:120px`

Comment: Thank you.Everything looks fine now

Comment: Please take out the reference to my answer. If I delete or change it, it will invalidate your answer, but thanks for the thought though.

Comment: Thats the reason I added the code as well. And dont delete it, Its right too, as the OP didn't mention he wanted a fixed width. It might help someone in future :)

Comment: @GurgenHayrapetyan it would be nice if you can mark an answer from wich ever solution helped you from all these responses. It might help someone in future

Comment: @LGSon after your update I recommend you to keep your answer. It has good pointers +1.

Answer (score 2):

You solve that by changing `style="width: 120px; ..."` to `style="min-width: 120px; ..."`

Then your button will be minimum 120px wide and grow with the text if it gets wider.

*Update: If you keep the fixed width and set `white-space: normal`, the text will break line.*

```css
button {
  min-width: 120px;
}

button:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 120px;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<button>Short text</button><br>
<button>Long long long long long text</button><br>
<button>Long long long long long text</button>
```

Comment: But I need fixed width. By using min-width: 120px, width of that button  automatically  increased.I want to cut that  diference

Comment: @GurgenHayrapetyan Then you pick _Reddy_'s answer :)

Comment: @GurgenHayrapetyan, You never mentioned that in question. The above answer was correct in this phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `style="width: auto;"`

Comment: but this "auto" property increases button width for long texts. I want to cut that difference and don't change button width.

Comment: You want width 120px fix?

Answer (score 0):

use auto width property of css this will auto fit the width of button .

```
width:auto;
```

Answer (score 0):

chose one of them hope one solution match your needs

**Snippet**

```css
#button1{
  width:120px;
  background:red;
  padding:20px;
  color:white;
}
#button2{
  width:120px;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding:20px;
  color:white;
   }
   #button3{
 min-width:120px;
  background:red;
 padding:20px;
 color:white;
   }
   #button4{
 width:120px;
 background:red;
 word-break: break-all;
 padding:20px;
 color:white;
   }
```

```html
<button id="button1" >text</button>
<button id="button2" >textttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt </button> 
<button id="button3"   > texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</button>
<button id="button4" >texttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt</button>
```